# I started Mininet, after generating xterm, encountered a connection that was rejected

Tags: sdn, mininet

I opened the mininet after running the following command:

```
$sudo mn -x
```

The following command was run in the switch window of Xterm:

```
$dpctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6634
```

The following error arises:

> dpctl: failed to send packet to switch: Connection refused

I do not know what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

try this command,

```
sudo ovs-ofctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6634
```

[for More info](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/FAQ#dpctl)

Answer (score 1):

It may be port:6634 didn't connect to any switch, but is instead used by the controller.

Connecting to remote controller at 127.0.0.1:**6653**

You should use the next one port after the controller
eg. controller is at **6653**, so try port **6654**

You should use:

```
$ dpctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6654
```

if you have 2 switches
you can also use

```
dpctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6655
```

Comment: All constructive feedback is appreciated, but the bold / title formatting is a bit much. You could edit your answer to tone it down a bit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the port number.
startup Mininet in verbose mode and look at the passive listening ports for the switches when they’re created

running Mininet in verbose:

```
sudo mn -v debug
```

search for the line like this:

> 0*** c0 : ('echo A | telnet -e A 127.0.0.1 **6653**',)

Replace port# in:

```
$dpctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6634
```

with:

```
$dpctl dump-flows tcp:127.0.0.1:6653
```